# ScrollView : How to reproduce snapToInterval and snapToAlignment for Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm looking for a way to scroll my horizontal menu at a specific interval.

`I have multiple children visible on screen`

[image: I have multiple children visible on screen]

The selected state is at center.

The use of snapToInterval in combination with snapToAlignement fills exactly my needs, but these props are only for iOS.

Is there a way to achieve this ? I suppose the PanResponder API could be use but I have no clue how to implement it.

I use 0.28 RN version. Thanks.

```
<ScrollView
  decelerationRate={0}
  horizontal
  snapToAlignment="center"
  snapToInterval={150}
>
  {this.props.children}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi, I really need this feature also. I think trying with Pan would be the hard route. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @ssomnoremac Unfortunately, with the lack of support for now I ended up with a simpler menu. I searched for days, but my code seemed really hacky and the result wasn't satisfying.

Comment: I built a similar menu using a `ListView`, calculating the widths of the tabs, and then using `scrollTo` to move the `ListView`.  I'm not trying to center the header, just move it onto the screen, but that shouldn't be too much more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pull request regarding this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/15297

Also there is a library https://github.com/machadogj/react-native-carousel-control?files=1 that support for both Android and iOS swipe, it control the scrolling behaviour itself, but I tried it, it worked, but not that smooth compared with `snapToInterval` and `snapToAlignment`.

Another one, but more complex carousel swipe is here: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel

Hopefully, you will get more insights based on these.

Comment: @Yupichaks no worries, I actually tried the library https://github.com/machadogj/react-native-carousel-control?files=1, and refactored a lot of the code, control the swipe behaviour without rerender the whole `FlatList`, works nicely on android, but still not smooth compared with `snapToInterval` and `snapToAlignment`, missing the feature of fast swipe to smoothly jump to next page.

Comment: as of RN 0.53.0 this is now implemented also in android https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.53.0